# View SharePoint 2016 Document in a ASP.Net iFrame

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How do you configure SharePoint to allow an iFrame to render a document stored in a document library?

Example of what I'm trying from a simple **.Net IIS site**:

```
<td>
<iframe src="https://taco.net/Shared%20Documents/burrito.pdf" width="800" height="600">
</iframe>
</td>
```

The iFrame loads with this error:
This content cannot be displayed in a frame

This works:

```
<td>
<iframe src="https://taco.net/Shared%20Documents/" width="800" height="600">
</iframe>
</td>
```

But when I click on the PDF I'm greeted with this error:
This content cannot be displayed in a frame

Comment: Try checking this post on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294714/allow-others-to-iframe-my-site

Comment: Site stopped loading with the web.config change and my site does not have an HTTP Response X-Frame-Options listed.  Thx for the link